# two for loops in one list comprehension separately

Tags: python, list

```
def get_plus(x,y):
    return str(x) + y


seq_x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
seq_y = 'abc'
print([get_plus(x,y) for x in seq_x for y in seq_y])

#result // ['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c', '3a', '3b', '3c', '4a', '4b', '4c']
```

but, I'd like to make result like this

```
 #result // ['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

how can I do that?

Comment: read up on the `zip` command. :) . It should do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine iterables into another iterable of pairs:

```
>>> zip([1,2,3], [9,8,7,6])
<zip object at 0x7f289a116188>
>>> list(zip([1,2,3], [9,8,7,6]))
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7)]
```

NOTE: The returned iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

---

```
>>> def get_plus(x, y):
...     return str(x) + y
... 
>>> seq_x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> seq_y = 'abc'
>>> [get_plus(x,y) for x, y in zip(seq_x, seq_y)]
['1a', '2b', '3c']


>>> ['{}{}'.format(x,y) for x, y in zip(seq_x, seq_y)]  # Using str.format
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Comment: Im not a fan of the arbitrary typelessness.   I suggest either `str()` both, or just do:  `return "{}{}".format(x,y)` for consistency.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, updated the answer to use `str.format` as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to the rescue. Killer one-liner:

```
>>> [''.join(str(col) for col in row) for row in zip([1,2,3,4], 'abc')]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seq_x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
seq_y = 'abc'
print ([str(x)+y for x, y in zip(seq_x, seq_y)])
```

output:

```
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```